# What is the easiest way to send files to a USB device

Tags: usb

I am new to Ubuntu. I want to know about the easiest way to send files to a USB device. (ex. Pen drive, external hard disk etc.)

My Ubuntu version is 14.10.

N.B:

1) I am sorry if this is a very basic question. But it is hard for me to figure out the solution.

2) Is it possible from command line?

Answer (score 2):

When you plug in the stick, it will probably auto-mount, ie open a new window. If not, there should be a new icon appear on your desktop; double-click will mount it.
You can then either use drag-and-drop in the usual way; or use a terminal & type `cp yourfilehere /media/your newly mounted stick`
Once copied, you should use the unmount symbol next to the drive name on the window; or type `sync ; sudo umount /media/your newly mounted stick`
Then you can remove the stick; job done.